# Passing a map to Grails JSON view gson template can't pass values everything is null

Tags: json, grails, gson

The following action:

```
def addMembers(){
    Map result = [message:"successful"]
    try {
        def group = Group.get(params.id)
        def json = request.JSON
        def users = json.users.collect{Usr.get(it.id)}
        result.members = groupService.addMembers(group,users)
    }catch(Exception e){
        message = "Exception $e"
        result.message = message
        response.setStatus(hsr.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
    }
    respond result, [model:[result:result]]
}//eo addMember
```

In conjunction with the following addMembers.gson file

```
model {
    Map result
}

json{
    message result.message
    members g.render(template:"simpleMember", collection: result.members, var:'member')
}
```

Gets a null pointer exception:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'message' on null object

I have things working well in other actions where I respond domain objects but the client side needs a message if I catch an exception and it really didn't seem worth it to create an arbitrary pogo when [message:"",members:[]] could do the same amount of work as an arbitrary extra file and an extra 5-10 lines of code.

**Update 1**
I tried replacing Map with an arbitrary ResultHolder class to placate any strict typing that might have been in play.

That didn't help

**Update 2**
In my .gson file I replaced

```
json{
```

with

```
json g.render(result){
```

And that gets me null output instead of null pointers.

Equally unacceptable.

Update 3
In order to try to assess how to interact with gson template without depending on ajax posts and database interaction I make the following arbitrary action:

```
def jsonDbug(){
    def result = [message:"hi"]
    respond result, [model:[jsonDbug:result]]
}
```

and an arbitrary gson file:

```
model{
    Map jsonDebug
}

json{
    says jsonDebug.message
}
```

This allows me to make changes faster to see what is going wrong.
I'm trying calling in other ways except respond now but nothing works.

It's as if JSON views are strictly for domain objects and nothing else.

Comment: I just tried creating an arbitrary ResultHolder class updated my gson file to replace Map with ResultHolder and use it within my action in lieu of my groovy map literal and still no message on null object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I wasn't that very far off when I started.
The problem was:

```
respond result, [model:[result:result]]
```

Which is the predominant example used at http://views.grails.org/latest/

When I changed to:

```
render(view:"addMembers", model:[result:result])
```

It worked exactly how I wanted it to.

Comment: Just what I needed Dave, surprised that render worked considering that the Grails Views documentation only uses the respond method.